# MySQL: Detect existence of at least 1 record in large joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

users (id, name)

user_activities (id, user_id, activity_id, created_at)

The user_activities table is very large with over 300 million rows.

I am trying to detect which users have done any activity between a given date range.  In other words, rows on the user table, where a joined row exists on the user_activities table between a certain created_at range.

I can do this with an INNER JOIN, GROUP BY and WHERE clause but the query runs for a long time as I believe its hitting all user_activities rows between my date range.

I don't really care "how many" activities, just if they've had more than zero.  So i am grouping to get a count (e.g. 210 activities) when actually I could stop after finding just 1.

Is there a more efficient way to do this rather than grouping all user_activity rows to count them?

For info, here's the current query, which works fine but take a long time:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, COUNT(ua.id) AS activity_count
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_activity ua ON u.id=ua.user_id
WHERE ua.created_at > '2017-01-01' AND ua.created_at < '2017-03-01'
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING activity_count > 0;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No HAVING needed here, no users without activities will be included. (I.e. activity_count will always be larger than 0.)

Comment: So I could remove the COUNT(ua.id) as well then?

Comment: Do you need to count the activities per user or would it suffice to know that the user was active (i.e. has at least one activity in the date range)?

Comment: Yes, not needed - as longs as you just want to know if there are any activities at all.

Comment: Just existence of at least 1 activity, I don't need to count how many in total.  I think Gordon's second answer below is doing this existence check so I will try that.

Comment: Gordon's second answer will return the correct answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this version:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM user_activity ua 
        WHERE u.id = ua.user_id AND
              ua.created_at > '2017-01-01' AND
              ua.created_at < '2017-03-01'
       ) as activity_count
FROM users u
HAVING activity_count > 0;
```

For performance you want an index on `user_activity(user_id, created_at)`.

EDIT:

If you just want existence, then use the same index and this should be much faster:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM user_activity ua 
              WHERE u.id = ua.user_id AND
                    ua.created_at > '2017-01-01' AND
                    ua.created_at < '2017-03-01'
              );
```

Whereas your query does complex processing and then aggregation of a bunch of data, this should scan the `users` table, and just look up in the index whether an appropriate activity exists for the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon, your second query is exactly what I want!

Comment: Seeing some of your work on predictive analytics, I thought you may dig this.  MIT has posted some lectures on AI.  Starts off a little slow, but it gets better.   http://www.openculture.com/2017/05/artificial-intelligence-a-free-online-course-from-mit.html   ...

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . As an undergraduate, I took my AI course at MIT from Patrick Winston.  I will not give my comments on a public forum ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Too funny.  I actually instructed at MIT.   My son was enrolled in the Summer Acadamy for Robotics (12 years old).  The instructor was out sick, so I took over the class for three days.   Never been brave enough to put that on my resume.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `EXISTS` clause, so the DBMS sees that it suffices to find one record per user in the given date range.

```
SELECT id, name
FROM users u
where exists
(
  select *
  from user_activity ua 
  where ua.user_id = u.id
  and ua.created_at > '2017-01-01' AND ua.created_at < '2017-03-01'
);
```

With this index:

```
create index idx on user_activity(user_id, created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get users who have done activities for a given date range

```
select u.id, u.name  from users u
    where exists ( SELECT 1  FROM user_activity ua 
        where ua.user_id = u.id 
        and ua.created_at > '2017-01-01' AND
              ua.created_at < '2017-03-01')
```

Create index for user_activity(created_at)

Answer (score 0):

If its only for testing existence, then:

```
SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT u.id
        FROM user_activity AS ua 
        WHERE u.id = ua.user_id 
            AND ua.created_at > '2017-01-01' 
            AND ua.created_at < '2017-03-01'
) AS ret
```

this will simply return column
ret = 1 
if at least a row of query will satisfy given conditions, else it will return column
ret = 0